# Why exec doesn't run while safe_mode is off?

Tags: php, apache, apache2

disable_functions = empty

safe_mode = off

exec, system, passthru, shell_exec return nothing for command 'top -n 1'.

That command works ok though SSH.

Comment: Nothing does not mean the commands are not executed or not working...

Comment: Those commands suppose to execute AND return result.

Comment: Think about what output you actually expect. Those commands can only return real output of an executed command, but `top` does not write any output. That is why you get an empty result. Have a try using another command like `echo 'hi there!'`. `top` is an interactive tool that works by manipulating the terminal, not by writing output to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the `top` command does not produce "normal" output. 
To use the command the way you want to, you have to take care to actually receive something on the commands standard output pipe. Have a try using this command inside your `exec()` statement:

```
top -b -n 1
```